# Rounding Real number

Tags: numerics, arithmetic, rounding

I have real numbers in array, I want to round (or truncate) these numbers to 2-digit after decimal point, then I want to write values to Excel File
For example if I have

```
t = {75.34123, 80.567,  85.789};
```

I want to have after rounding

```
t = {75.34, 80.56, 85.78};
```

then I want to export it to excel file.
First I use N function but it shows number as I want and leave it in background as it was. so when I export it it writes the number as it before rounding.
I found Solution that use "Computer Arithmetic" package and ComputerNumber Function that give me what I want, but when I export to excel it writes number as formula not as value.
so I need solution that gives real Rounding so the number becomes as 2-digit after decimal point in all calculations, and writes these numbers as values to excel file.
Thank you.

Comment: You mean truncating not rounding - as rounding would turn 85.789 into 85.79. You could look at using `NumberForm[t, 4]`

Comment: NumberForm Shows number as I want but in memory it stays as it, so if I use in some calculation it use 85.789 instead of 85.79, so it is not what I want.

Comment: Do you want exact decimal rounding or a 64-bit binary floating-point approximation?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Round` and specify the second argument,

```
t = {75.34123, 80.567, 85.789};
Round[t, 0.01]
(* {75.34, 80.57, 85.79} *)
```

to truncate, you can use the `IntegerPart` trick in the other answer.

Comment: thank you. I found Round Function but I did not know how to use the second parameter

Answer (score 5):

```
t = {75.34123, 80.567, 85.789};
t2 = IntegerPart[100 t]/100 // N
Export["C:\\t2.xls", t2]
```

Answer (score 4):

Truncating (toward zero), if including negative reals:

```
t = {75.34123, 80.567, 85.789, -13.579};
Sign[t] Floor[RealAbs[t], 0.01]
(*  {75.34, 80.56, 85.78, -13.57}  *)
```

If negative numbers not a concern, or truncating toward negative infinity:

```
Floor[t, 0.01]
(*  {75.34, 80.56, 85.78, -13.58}  *)
```